# Название видео с ссылки на Ютуб

Tags: html, youtube, php, javascript

Картинку можно взять c img.youtube.com/vi/7L2fsubA2-c/0.jpg, а Где взять название ролика, например с адреса.
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7L2fsubA2-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**gdata.youtube.com**](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/7L2fsubA2-c?alt=json&v=2)

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{id_video}?alt=json&v=2
```

Comment: Спасибо, а не знаете ли вы случайно еще адреса в ВК, для картинки видео и названия?

Comment: @Zow, читайте документацию UserAPI VK

Answer (score 1):

[YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) `->` [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

Answer (score 0):

[cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.curl.php) + регулярное выражение для `<title>Название ролика - Youtube</title>`